# Change Text in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

quick question,
I'm tying to see if there's an option to change text (layer) in forge viewer via script
For example to change language or toggle between Metric and Imperial

images:

Forge Viewer :

[image]

Autocad :

[image]

my other option is to have a layer for each option, but I'm not sure that's my best option

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately once the model data (both geometry and properties) is extracted it stays immutable so it's not exactly possible to modify the model after it's converted by Forge.

One possible workaround would be to hide the text (find its node id(dbid) and do `viewer.hide(dbid)`) and programmatically text markups (using Viewer's built-in [markups extension](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html)) to display the desired text, say e.g.:

```
 //programmatically create text markups:
 const styleObject = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.Utils.createStyle(['font-size'], window.ext);
 styleObject['font-size'] = 100;
 (new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.CreateText(window.ext, 2333, {x:20,y:20}, {x:100,y:100},'233', styleObject)).execute()
```

Comment: ya, I thought so, Thanks for the quick response :)